# Navigation Back Button Update

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have 3 views: A, B, and C.  They are connected by segues this way:

```
A->B
A->C
B->C
```

When I transition from B to C, I want the view to be removed from the navigation stack.  I use this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753659/2260928 to remove B.  It works fine except for the back button that still has B as the label. When I press back, it transitions to A with a back button label of A and if I press back button again the button disappears.

How can I fix this weird back button behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to the question but an alternate way of achieving the behavior I wanted: [Removing viewcontrollers from navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281545/removing-viewcontrollers-from-navigation-stack)